# Dell Inspiron 13 7000 2-in-1 linux support

Tags: dell, compatibility

I’m planning on buying the brand new Dell Inspiron 13 7000 2in1 with the base configuration. Does anybody have experience or knowledge of whether or not ubuntu based distros will run smoothly on that specific laptop? I see on the ubuntu certified that the old model works but I can’t find the newest one. If it does, what kernel is required for it to work? I am technically wanting to run elementary OS Loki but I came here because eOS is based on ubuntu obviously.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware recommendation **and** not about Ubuntu.

Comment: How about we change the tag instead

Comment: EOS is off-topic here but since you asked this is the [Recommended System Specifications](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications) Questions can asked at [elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I have an Inspiron 17 7000 series 2in1 and the ubuntu experience is near flawless.  A simple install too. My only possible issue is lower battery life, but not sure of the cause yet.